# how can I use button when only I selected an option kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button

here I have four option and I want to disable submit when the player click it before selected an option
so that mean I want to enable submit only when the player select one option
here is my code its an Quiz app

```
 setQuestion()

    tv_option_one.setOnClickListener(this)
    tv_option_two.setOnClickListener(this)
    tv_option_three.setOnClickListener(this)
    tv_option_four.setOnClickListener(this)
    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(this)
}



override fun onClick(v: View?) {

    when (v?.id) {


        R.id.tv_option_one -> {

            selectedOptionView(tv_option_one, 1)
        }

        R.id.tv_option_two -> {

            selectedOptionView(tv_option_two, 2)

        }

        R.id.tv_option_three -> {

            selectedOptionView(tv_option_three, 3)

        }

        R.id.tv_option_four -> {

            selectedOptionView(tv_option_four, 4)

        }

        R.id.btn_submit -> {



            if (mSelectedOptionPosition == 0) {

                mCurrentPosition++


                when {

                    mCurrentPosition <= mQuestionsList!!.size -> {

                        setQuestion()
                        tv_option_one.isClickable = true
                        tv_option_two.isClickable = true
                        tv_option_three.isClickable = true
                        tv_option_four.isClickable = true
```

***// here i guess we should do the code***

```
                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make button disabled initially and once the user chooses any option, then you can enable it.

Add the following line in the function `setQuestion()`

```
btn_submit.isEnabled = false
```

And in **each** of those options in the `onClick()` function, you can add like this:

```
R.id.tv_option_one -> {
    btn_submit.isEnabled = true  
    selectedOptionView(tv_option_one, 1)
}
```

Instead, if you want the button to completely disappear and appear only when the user choses an option, you can use the following code:

```
btn_submit.alpha = false
```

and

```
R.id.tv_option_one -> {
    btn_submit.alpha = true  
    selectedOptionView(tv_option_one, 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the visibility of the button to `GONE` initially in `onCreate()` and then change its visibility to `VISIBLE` in each `OnClickListener` or you can make the button `setEnabled(false)` initially also in `onCreate()` and then set it to `setEnabled(true)` in each `OnClickListener`.

For example,

```
myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE)
R.id.tv_option_one -> myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

OR

```
myButton.setEnabled(false)
R.id.tv_option_one -> myButton.setEnabled(true)
```